# Rails exclude current_user from selection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Rails app where
user has_one employee
employee belongs_to workgroup
workorder belongs_to workgroup
workorder belongs_to employee  (this is the lead)

The following works to list all the workorders in the current_user's workgroup.

```
  <% current_user.workgroup.workorders.each do |workorder| %>
```

I want to display workorders for a group, but exclude the current_user.  In other words I want to display all the workorders in the user's group that he/she isn't the lead.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
<% current_user.workgroup.workorders.where(employee_id != current_user.employee_id).each do |workorder| %>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the solution:
`<% Workorders.where('employee_id != ?', current_user.id).each do |workorder| %>`

Comment: But, they need to be workorders assigned the the employee's workgroup - not just workorders that aren't assigned to the employee.

Comment: You got me going in the right direction.  This worked: <%  Workorder.where("employee_id != ? AND workgroup_id = ?", current_user.employee.id, current_user.employee.workgroup.id).each do |workorder| %>

Comment: Ops, I didn't grasp the "workgroup" part, but glad to have been helpful